# Минимальный пример для создания локальной SQLite базы данных на Java + Spring

Tags: java, spring, sqlite

Если в Android и Universal Windows Platform приложениях создать локальную SQLite-базу (по сути файл) очень просто, то почему-то в для обычных Java-приложенияй (не Android) информации о том, как это сделать, очень мало. Если набрать запрос типа "java sqlite", то в большинстве результатов поиска будет предполагаться, что БД находится на сервере, отсюда - рулоны кода с настройками и конфигурациями.

Цель данного вопроса - получение очищенного от всяких "наворотов" минимального кода для создания локальной SQLite-базы и одной таблицы с использованием подходящей Spring-библиотеки. Дальше я и другие читатели увидев, что Вы используете, сможем по аналогии и по документации к данной библиотеке реализовать остальные транзакции с БД.

Я подготовил начальный шаблон кода для главного класса приложения и pom.xml:

```
public class EntryPoint {

  public static void main (String[] args) {

        String PATH_TO_DB_FILE = '';

        if(!/* проверка файла на существание */) {
            // создаём его
        } 

        // получаем доступ к файлу

        // создаём таблицу

        // Spring должен закрыть за нас поток работы с файлом
  }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Какой-нибудь конструктов SQL-запросов от Spring -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232892/spring-boot-and-sqlite

Comment: https://github.com/bharat0126/springboot-sqlite-app

Comment: Зачем в спринге sqlite если есть h2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Структура каталогов

```
│   pom.xml
│
└───src
    └───main
        ├───java
        │   └───com
        │       └───example
        │               App.java
        │
        └───resources
                context.xml
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>minimal-sqlite</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Minimal Spring + SQLite example</name>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.25.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:test.db"/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

App.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = context.getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE some_table (id SERIAL, some_field VARCHAR(255), another_field VARCHAR(255))");
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Проанализировал Ваш код. Перед тем, как его запустить, хотел бы уточнить один непонятный для меня момент. Скажите пожалуйста, где создаётся эта самая база данных? Это должен быть какой-то файл, который где-то хранится...

Comment: Свойство `url` бина `dataSource` указывает на этот файл. В данном случае файл будет создан в рабочем каталоге программы, то есть там, где вы её запустите.

Comment: Запустил Ваш код - всё работает! Благодарю Вас за ответ! Конечно, осталось много непонятных моментов, но они уже будут в других вопросах.